# «То есть» в конце предложения. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Отделяется ли запятой от предшествующих слов "то есть", замыкающее предложение?
Предлагаю рассмотреть такой пример:
*Полоса — запечатанная площадь страницы любого издания, на которой размещается набор текста (иллюстрации). **Без полей, то есть.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Странный у вас текст. Первая фраза явно книжная: сложноподчиненное предложение, причастие есть. А второе - добавление чисто разговорного стиля. Исходя из коммуникативных целей (для чего нужна фраза? Где будет использована?)составьте фразу, потом думайте о знаках. Я бы ввела это "без полей" в первое предложение или второе составила бы в стиле первого.

Если отвлечься от содержания и стиля предложения, тогда нет, запятая не нужна,  союз то есть вводит пояснительную часть. Вы ее уже отделили точкой.

Comment: Я согласна, что "без полей" лучше было бы включить в первое предложение, так как это сочетание, насколько я могу судить "с высоты" своего невежества, не может формировать самостоятельное предложение. Но автор закавыченного текста пожелал оформить свою ремарку как самостоятельную синтаксическую единицу.
Можно, конечно, в качестве примера взять более стилистически однородный текст (например: "Ее отец - университетский преподаватель. Профессор, (?) то есть").

Comment: За комментарий по существу спасибо. Просто я не привыкла к тому, что союзы присоединяют обособленные члены, располагаясь в арьергарде, оттого и возникают такие вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

*Полоса – запечатанная площадь страницы любого издания, на которой размещается набор текста (иллюстрации). **Без полей то есть**.*

Запятая не нужна: ***Без полей то есть**.*

Это нестандартная конструкция: пояснительный союз ТО ЕСТЬ стоит в конце оборота, к тому же сам оборот отделен от предложения (метод парцелляциии текста на отдельные фрагменты).

Тем не менее союз относится к обособленном у обороту и не отделяется от него (паузой или запятой).

По аналогии **вводные слова** в конце  оборота также обособляются вместе с ним: *Встретимся в ближайшее время, **завтра например**.*

Пример:

– *Перчик, будь другом, дай пять монет до получки, **до завтра то есть**…* [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Улитка на склоне (1966-1968)]

Comment: Стоп, но на "полей" же есть ударение (ну и небольшая пауза как следствие). Здесь не обособленный оборот, а предложение — вводное слово бы отделялось! Давайте ещё авторитетные примеры, чтобы показать, что мнение писателей совпадает (если это так). Желательно с предложением, а не с обособленным оборотом, как у Стругацких.

Comment: @oleedd Вот, "нарыла". 1. Начнём, пожалуй, с критики в её исходном смысле. **С негатива то есть**. [Андрей Пермяков. Марафон начинается после тридцатого километра // «Волга», 2015]. 2. То ли святому Иоанну (**Ивану то есть**) Крестителю, который как раз в эти дни родился. [В ночь на Ивана-Купалу // «Трамвай», 1990]. 3. *Он продал ее после смерти жены, **вашей подруги то есть*** (М. Серова. Штрихкод греха).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Только в первом примере это предложение, а не оборот. Хотелось авторитетных писателей (известных). А малоизвестных (как у вас) в Нацкорпусе и сам могу найти. Есть ли что-то типа Нацкорпуса, но по классике? Кстати, "то есть" может быть вводным словом, что указано в словаре Фрамполя.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова В Нацкорпусе присутствуют оба варианта: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?spp=50&text=lexgramm&kwsz=5&sampling=1&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&spd=10&out=normal&flags3=last&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod1=sem&nodia=1&parent2=0&sort=i_grtagging&format=html&min2=1&min3=1&lang=ru&lex1=%2A&lex3=есть&g=i_doc&dpp=10&max2=1&sr=1&lex2=то&parent3=0&mode=main&parent1=0&max3=1

Comment: _oleedd: Кстати, "то есть" может быть вводным словом, что указано в словаре Фрамполя._ === **Фрамполя**?  Автор словаря – женщина: Фрамполь Ольга Дмитриевна.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Из Грамматики Кустовой** ([ссылка; стр. 119](https://dokumen.pub/qdownload/78e177608bc79c4dcdef45f878bfe4cf.html))

*Собственно **пояснение** основано на логических отношениях тождества и является **повторным наименованием** уже названного.*

*В большинстве случаев тождество обозначений не вытекает из лексического значения слов, **а устанавливается говорящим:** На следующий день, то есть в пятницу, все собрались у Игоря.*

***Языковыми средствами** формирования пояснительной конструкции являются:

— особая «предупредительная» интонация;

— союзы то есть (то бишь, сиречь), или (не путать с разделительным союзом или), а именно, как то, будь то;

— служебные слова вернее, точнее, иначе говоря, попросту говоря, лучше сказать, которые могут выступать как самостоятельно, так и в сочетании с союзами: или, иначе; или, лучше сказать.*

*Пояснение может быть как **повторным наименованием, так и конкретизацией, «расшифровкой»** общего понятия путем перечисления входящих в него элементов.*

2. Итак, мы  повторяем (разъясняем)  **уже сказанное**, используя  какие-то **МЕТКИ** – чаще всего **союз ТО ЕСТЬ**. Разумеется, этот союз не может находиться под ударением.
3. **А вот инверсия союза возможна**. Что она нам дает? При инверсии обычное  (тоническое) ударение в конце фразы переходит в логическое, то есть **подчеркивается.** Разумеется, двух ударений быть не может. Так мы выделяем  **основное содержание фразы**, ставя ее в ударную фонетическую позицию.
4. **Парцелляция ничего не меняет**. В любом случае союз будет находиться в безударной позиции, а ударением выделяется основное содержание.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ваше мнение, как вы говорите.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, запятая нужна в связи с логическими ударениями:
*То есть без полЕй.

Без полЕй, тО есть.* || Два ударения. Инверсия.

При инверсии часто ставится запятая (или тире), тогда как при обычном порядке её нет. В том числе в примерах Розенталя из различных параграфов.

Разве может союз, присоединяющий что-то, быть в конце им присоединяемого? Это вряд ли. Тогда это уже не союз.

Comment: *Рассмотрим это предложение с союзом, к тому же присоединительным.* Вы согласны, что "к тому же" здесь союз, и что он присоединительный? Что изменится, если поменять порядок слов во второй части: "присоединительным к тому же"? Неужели Вам никогда не попадались подобные конструкции? Я могу привести тысячи таких примеров из Нацкорпуса.

Comment: "К тому же" тесно примыкает за счёт предлога, а "то есть" нет, поэтому в Нацкорпусе есть и с запятой.

Comment: Вы совсем не поняли мой комментарий. Ну хорошо, я попытаюсь объяснить понятнее. Вот Ваш вопрос: *Разве может союз, присоединяющий что-то, быть в конце им присоединяемого?* Вот мой ответ: "Да. Тысячу раз да."

Comment: Ладно, принял. Я не просто так спрашивал, а не утверждал. Если так, то "союзность" такого союза частично нивелируется. Тогда она лишь смысловая, уже не структурная. А для союзов важно последнее. Но подобные сочетания слов как раз считаются союзами из-за того, что стоят в начале. Попробуйте настоящие союзы переставить в конец (*и, или, но, а*). Поэтому это всё спорно. Вы тоже не поняли этот мой вопрос. Там не о том, может ли союз быть в конце, а о том, является ли союзное сочетание в такой позиции союзом.