# Она тебя обняла(,) то есть?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Можно заменить *то есть* посредством *другими словами* здесь.

> Как всё прошло? Она тебя обняла(,) то есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Как всё прошло? Она тебя обняла **то есть?***

Запятая не нужна, инверсия пояснительного союза. Тема уже обсуждалась на форуме.

Пояснительный союз в данном случае имеет дополнительное значение **присоединительного** союза.

Фразу можно записать так: *Она тебя обняла, **точнее говоря**.* Вводное сочетание в такой позиции обособляется, но союз обособляться **не может.**

**["То есть" в конце предложения. Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28311/%D0%A2%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).**